# Is a polytope with vertices on a sphere and all edges of same length already rigid?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes

Let's say $P\subset\Bbb R^d$ is some *convex* polytope with the following two properties:

1. all vertices are on a common sphere.
2. all edges are of the same length.

I suspect that such a polytope is already rigid, i.e. there is (up to scaling and rotation) only a single way to realize it geometrically. Is this true? What if we only look at uniform polytopes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you also fix the combinatorial structure. Then yes. Induct in dimension with obvious base $d\leqslant 2$. By induction proposition the facets are fixed. By Cauchy - - Alexandrov rigidity theorem the whole polytope also is fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have any source for the rigidity theorem in dimension $d>3$? Also, is there anything obvious to say if I do not fix the combinatorial type, but just the edge-graph?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but what makes a (say) triangular prism rigid, especially if it is twisted slightly? Gerhard "Maybe The Definitions Are Tweaked?" Paseman, 2019.03.10.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman if you "twist" the triangular prism, the square faces are "folded" into two triangular faces each. This is what Fedor meant with fixing the combinatorial structure. Also, you create new edges which are now probably not of the same length as the others.

Comment: Even if you fix the sphere, I have two ways of embedding the prism (assuming the edges are hinged). Is a continuous motion on the sphere surface desired? Gerhard "Trying To See It Mentally" Paseman, 2019.03.10.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman No, a continuous motion is not required. Which two ways do you see?

Comment: Right hand twist and left hand twist. Gerhard "Baby Let's Do The Twist!" Paseman, 2019.03.10.

Comment: Wiki page of it seems to have a reference to Alexandrov's work

Comment: @FedorPetrov Not really (or I can't see it). The relevant sentence in Wikipedia has no link to a source, and all the other sources in the end of the article seem to only talk about *polyhedra*, not polytopes (especially Alexandrov's book).

Comment: Hm. What is the difference?

Comment: @FedorPetrov [This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/372286/108884) to another question of mine made me think that there might be some details missing in this answer that are not obvious to fix. Cauchy's theorem seems to need more than just congruent faces, and I have no idea what a higher dimensional analogue might need.

Comment: @M.Winter but the facets are fixed as labelled polytopes, do not they?

Comment: @FedorPetrov I don't think that we get a labeling out of my question straight away. Anyway, I still think this approach works after I considered an extended version of Cauchy's theorem (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/373828/108884), especially the last theorem almost at the bottom of the question).