# Which polytopes can be deformed while keeping their edge-lengths?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, hypercube

Let $P\subset\Bbb R^d$ be a convex polytope (a convex hull of finitely many points). Lets call it *flexible*, if it can be continuously deformed while

- keeping its combinatorial type, and
- keeping its edge-lengths.

I know that the $d$-cube is flexible in this sense.
More generally, most (all?) zonotopes are flexible (see the comments). Also all polygons are flexible. But are there any others?

$\quad\quad$[image]

I also know that there are polytopes having several realizations with matching edge-lengths (e.g. see the image [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/372979/108884)), but these realizations cannot be continuously deformed into each other while preserving all edge-lengths.

Comment: Possibly: All zonohedra?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Oh I see. I suspect you mean to generate a polytope $$Z=\sum\mathrm{conv}\{-r_i,r_i\}$$ for some (generic) unit vectors $r_i$, and then you change these unit vectors continuously. So the question might be whether there are any that are not zonohedra/zonotopes (or polygons)? Is it still okay for me to edit the question?

Comment: Sure, please edit as you see fit.

Comment: What about a pentagonal cylinder, i.e. $\{(\cos 2\pi n/5, \sin 2\pi n/5, \pm 1)\}$? Or a cylinder of any other polygon?

Comment: @MattF. Right. A prism over any flexible polytope is flexible. Probably the same holds for the cartesian product of a flexible polytope and an arbitrary polytope. What about Minkowsi sums? It might be useful to find the "elementary" flexible polytopes.

Comment: Perhaps, it is also better to search for “minimal” ones. E.g., you may glue anything to a facet of a cube, and it remains flexible (although with less freedom). Perhaps, you are not interested in such examples?

Comment: What I take a away from this discussion in the comments is, that there are many more flexible polytopes than what I have naively assumed. So I suppose I have to rethink this question. I still think it would be interesting to ask whether there are any "unexpected" flexible polytopes, that are not polygons, zonotopes, or are created by products, Minkowski sums, gluing, or any other (not yet considered) "trivial" process. But this should certainly be made more precise. In any way, thanks to all of you for your input.

Comment: maybe looking [structural rigidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_rigidity) is helpful. In the linked article it is stated that "**In any dimension, the rigidity of rod-and-hinge linkages is described by a matroid**"